# Pipes unfolds composition

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I am currently in the process of learning pipes. While playing around with bidirectional pipes I noticed that unfold composition looks pretty similar:

```
(//>) :: Monad m => Proxy x' x b' b m r -> (b -> Proxy x' x c' c m b') -> Proxy x' x c' c m r
-- instead of:
(//>) :: Monad m => Proxy x' x b' b m r -> (b -> Proxy b' b c' c m b') -> Proxy x' x c' c m r
```

But we have to share the x' and x types because of the way we [wire up](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.2/docs/src/Pipes-Core.html#%2F%2F%3E) the continuation:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => Proxy a' a b' b m r -> (r -> Proxy a' a b' b m r') -> Proxy a' a b' b m r'
case p0 of
    Request x' fx  -> Request x' (\x -> go (fx x))
    Respond b  fb' -> fb b >>= \b' -> (fb' b')
    ...
```

But that's pretty easy to get around:

```
import Pipes
import Pipes.Core hiding ((//>))

main :: IO ()
main = runEffect $ lhs //> rhs

infixl 4 //>
(//>) :: Monad m => Proxy x' x b' b m r -> (b -> Proxy b' b c' c m b') -> Proxy x' x c' c m r
p //> f = p >>~ go
    where go x = go =<< request =<< f x

lhs :: Proxy x' x String String IO ()
lhs = each [1..10::Int] //> \i -> do
    r <- respond $ "response nr. " ++ show i
    lift . putStrLn $ "lhs: " ++ show r

rhs :: String -> Proxy String String  x x' IO String
rhs x = do
    lift . putStrLn $ "rhs 1: " ++ show x
    y <- request "yield manually to upstream!"
    lift . putStrLn $ "rhs 2: " ++ show y
    return "return to upstream"
```

With the expected output:

```
rhs 1: "response nr. 1"
lhs: "yield manually to upstream!"
rhs 2: "response nr. 2"
lhs: "return to upstream"
rhs 1: "response nr. 3"
lhs: "yield manually to upstream!"
rhs 2: "response nr. 4"
lhs: "return to upstream"
rhs 1: "response nr. 5"
lhs: "yield manually to upstream!"
rhs 2: "response nr. 6"
lhs: "return to upstream"
rhs 1: "response nr. 7"
lhs: "yield manually to upstream!"
rhs 2: "response nr. 8"
lhs: "return to upstream"
rhs 1: "response nr. 9"
lhs: "yield manually to upstream!"
rhs 2: "response nr. 10"
lhs: "return to upstream"
```

Best I can tell this doesn't break any laws either.

So finally here is my question: Why does Pipes use the current definition?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? As you've pointed out, this is "easy to get around", and neither type (the original or your modification) for `(//>)` is a subtype of the other, so your modification does not generalize the old function, nor is it a specialization. In other words, there are type-correct programs using `(//>)` which would not typecheck with your modification, and vice-versa. So why is your version 'better'? (As far as pipe laws go, I don't know enough about pipes to know if your function is indeed law abiding - hopefully someone else can verify that fact for you)

Comment: If you look at the diagram [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.2/docs/Pipes-Core.html#g:3) you can see that the x' and x type variables of g aren't actually used. I can't come up with any extra programs that this would allow for which couldn't be easily converted but maybe I am just missing something obvious. Although of course changing it now might be problematic?

Comment: The type variables *are* used, by the type system (of Haskell, over which `pipes` has no control). It is the values 'represented' by those type parameters which are unused. I also cannot come up with any such programs, but the fact stands, that since neither type is subtype of the other, there do *exist* such programs, even if they are wildly complicated, impractical, what have you. ...

Comment: ... But the question still stands - why is your version better? It is not a strict generalization - so what does it offer that the original doesn't? Ignoring that making such a change in a long-existing library would be catastrophic to users of the library - even if you had the opportunity to rewrite pipes from the ground up, what would be the motivation to use your version over the current one?

Comment: With the library version g can only take a single value when called and return a single value when finished. This version starts the same but is also allowed to further communicate. Turns out that makes it impossible to write producer1 //> producer2 with my function if producer2 is explicitly defined as `Producer a m r`, though. Since the entire point of the combinator is to chain producers that seems like a deal breaker. Still kind of wish pipes would ship with some combinators for bidirectional pipes, though. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the relevant part of [`(//>)`'s contract](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.2/docs/Pipes-Core.html#v:-47--47--62-) is...

> `(p //> f)` replaces each `respond` in `p` with `f`.

... which implies that `f` will handle all values received from `p` in the same manner. That, however, is exactly what your combinator circumvents -- in your example, you alternate between sets of messages as you go through the elements of `each [1..10]`. To further illustrate the point, here is a slightly modified version of your code (in particular, I have picked a different name for your combinator, and used plain old `(//>)` immediately after `each [1..10]`, as your combinator behaves the same in that case):

```
infixl 4 //>*
(//>*) :: Monad m =>
    Proxy x' x b' b m r -> (b -> Proxy b' b c' c m b') -> Proxy x' x c' c m r
p //>* f = p >>~ go
    where go x = f x >>= request >>= go

src :: Monad m => Producer Int m ()
src = each [1..10]

-- The types of lhs and rhs are more restrictive than yours, but for this
-- usage pattern (and with the adjustments I made) that is not a problem. 
lhs :: Show a => a -> Server String String IO ()
lhs = \i -> do
    r <- respond $ "response nr. " ++ show i
    lift . putStrLn $ "lhs: " ++ r

rhs :: String -> Client String String IO String
rhs x = do
    lift . putStrLn $ "rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?"
    lift . putStrLn $ "rhs 1: " ++ x
    y <- request "yield manually to upstream!"
    lift . putStrLn $ "rhs 2: " ++ y
    return "return to upstream"
```

The answer to the question I slipped in at the beginning of `rhs`...

```
GHCi> runEffect $ (src //> lhs) //>* rhs
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 1
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 2: response nr. 2
lhs: return to upstream
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 3
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 2: response nr. 4
lhs: return to upstream
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 5
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 2: response nr. 6
lhs: return to upstream
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 7
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 2: response nr. 8
lhs: return to upstream
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 9
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 2: response nr. 10
lhs: return to upstream
```

... is no. Contrast that with what happens when I wire your functions using `(//>)` as the outermost combinator, like this:

```
GHCi> runEffect $ src //> (\x -> lhs x //>* rhs)
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 1
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 2
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 3
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 4
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 5
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 6
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 7
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 8
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 9
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 10
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
```

Instead of setting a server that will give at most ten responses (`src //> lhs`), here every value gives rise to a single-response server, whose response is handled by the `rhs` client. Given that there is no second response to be gotten out of the server, the code in `rhs` after the `request` is never ran. As a consequence, the values from `src` are handled uniformly. To further emphasise that, note that using your combinator to do that is unnecessary: `src //> (lhs >~> void . rhs)` does the same thing.

(Another thing to note is that, if we change back the types of `lhs` and `rhs` to what you had them to be at first, we can write the pipeline just above as `src //>* (\x -> lhs x //>* rhs)`. However, that is not the same as `(src //>* lhs) //>* rhs`. That is an associativity failure, and so your combinator does not give rise to a category.)

It also helps to clarify what is going on to replace your combinator with `(>>~)` (something that I'm sure you have tried in your tests):

```
GHCi> runEffect $ (src //> lhs) >>~ void . rhs
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 1
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 2: response nr. 2
```

`src //> lhs` offers up to ten responses; `rhs`, however, only makes two requests, and so the other eight responses are left unused. To me, that suggests your combinator is best expressed as a way to make a client carry on requesting indefinitely:

```
-- requestForever :: Monad m => (b -> Client b' b m b') -> b -> Client b' b m r
requestForever :: Monad m => 
    (b -> Proxy b' b c' c m b') -> b -> Proxy b' b c' c m r
requestForever f = go
    where go x = f x >>= request >>= go
```

```
GHCi> runEffect $ (src //> lhs) >>~ requestForever rhs
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 1
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 2: response nr. 2
lhs: return to upstream
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 3
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 2: response nr. 4
lhs: return to upstream
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 5
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 2: response nr. 6
lhs: return to upstream
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 7
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 2: response nr. 8
lhs: return to upstream
rhs 0: Will this happen for every value?
rhs 1: response nr. 9
lhs: yield manually to upstream!
rhs 2: response nr. 10
lhs: return to upstream
```